# Structure of post types for TV Shows and episodes

Tags: customization, permalinks, links

Dear I would like to know how I can make a structure similar to this in wordpress, that the series seasons and episodes are interconnected, what function could I use?

example.com/serie/the-walking-dead/season-8/episodie-4/

Comment: What had you tried? How are you establishing relationships between seasons/episodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the custom post type as usual and then use the [Permalinks Customizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/) plugin to customize the permalinks as per your need.